# How can i get the last 10 weeks in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

```
SELECT WEEK( `date_posted` ) AS week, COUNT( 1 ) AS aantal
FROM `news`
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

This doesn't works. The output is:

```
    week  aantal
    52  41
    51  56
    50  49
    49  56
    48  62
```

But, we are not yet in week 52. What's wrong?

Comment: do you have data from last year in your table?

Comment: you have to evaluate WEEK(Now()) as maximum

Comment: Yes, i have the data in this en previous week etc.. available. And i can't use GROUP with the MAX(). Any idea else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT WEEK( `date_posted` ) AS week, COUNT( 1 ) AS aantal
FROM `news` 
WHERE `date_posted` >= (curdate() - interval 10 week)
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: SELECT WEEK( `date_posted` ) AS week, COUNT( 1 ) AS aantal
        FROM `news` 
        WHERE `date_posted` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 week)
        GROUP BY week
        ORDER BY week DESC
        LIMIT 0 , 10

Gives:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC LIMIT 0 , 10' at line 3

Comment: @Aar Happy to help! If this answer is acceptable and solves your issue, then be sure to accept it via the check mark on the left.  It will help future visitors and you get rep for accepting.